# Is there any rollback command in R?

Tags: r, command

Is there any  rollback command in R just as what is available in TSQL? If existing, It saves me time preparing multiple backups before running every sensitive command.

```
begin tran
...
rollback tran
```

Comment: You may as well just assign to a new variable name when making any sensitive changes to a variable. I don't see how you are making this parallel between R & SQL.

Comment: The package restorepoint may be worth a look..

Comment: Actually, I am not doing anything with SQL. Just trying to find a way to get rid of caring about the data. Also, because most of my task is updating data , I have to care about not destroying the data in every step!